# unable to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I want to split the string and assign the tokens to different fields, if the tokens size is not as expected it is throwing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`
When the data is as expected, it is showing the empty value.

Sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
         List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> useCaseIds = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> partner = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

         String s = "Annie-Marie--Joe"; // -NoData";
        // final String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782-Joe-NoData"; //showing empty value when printing the list.
         String[] tokens = s.split("-");

        switch (tokens.length) {
        case 1:
            firstNames.add(tokens[0]);
        case 2:
            lastNames.add(tokens[1]);
        case 3:
            useCaseIds.add(tokens[2]);
        case 4:
            partner.add(tokens[3]);
        case 5:
            comments.add(tokens[4]);
        default:
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("firstNames " + firstNames);
        System.out.println("lastNames " + lastNames);
        System.out.println("useCaseIds " + useCaseIds);
        System.out.println("partner " + partner);
        System.out.println("comments " + comments);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

--EDIT--
Modified the code as shown below.

```
final String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782-Joe"; // showing empty value when
// printing the list.
final String[] tokens = s.split("-");

switch (tokens.length) {
case 1:
    firstNames.add(tokens[0]);
    break;
case 2:
    lastNames.add(tokens[1]);
    break;
case 3:
    useCaseIds.add(tokens[2]);
    break;
case 4:
    partner.add(tokens[3]);
    break;
case 5:
    comments.add(tokens[4]);
    break;
default:
    break;
}

System.out.println("firstNames " + firstNames);
System.out.println("lastNames " + lastNames);
System.out.println("useCaseIds " + useCaseIds);
System.out.println("partner " + partner);
System.out.println("comments " + comments);
```

}

Output:

```
firstNames []
lastNames []
useCaseIds []
partner [Joe]
comments []
```

Why the firstNames,lastNames,..are blank in my above scenario.

Comment: My scenario is different, it is not the duplicate @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Comment: You forgot to add break statements after each case.

Comment: @Henry - Please see the edited code, the values are blank.Only the value in partner is showing in the output.

Comment: IMHO the break statements are left out intentionally.

Comment: What a you question? About ` ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or about the firstNames,lastNames,..are blank in above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your array `tokens` has only 4 elements. Therefore accessing tokens[4] is causing`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You might wonder how this statement even executed. It is because if you satisfy a switch case and if that switch case do not have break statement, it will execute the below statement as well.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));

[Annie, Marie, , Joe]
```

use `break` statement inside your cases.

> Why the firstNames,lastNames,..are blank in my above scenario.

I think you do not understand how the switch constructs works. Switch will execute only one case where your given parameter is satisfied *(Unless you forget to break)*

All you have to do is, reverse the switch statement so that depending on the number of tokens, your `Lists` will be fulfilled.

```
 switch (tokens.length) {
    case 5:
        comments.add(tokens[4]);                
    case 4:
        partner.add(tokens[3]);             
    case 3:
        useCaseIds.add(tokens[2]);
    case 2:
        lastNames.add(tokens[1]);
    case 1:
        firstNames.add(tokens[0]);
    default:
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a different order in your tricky switch statement:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
         List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> useCaseIds = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> partner = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

         //String s = "Annie-Marie--Joe"; // -NoData";
         final String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782-Joe-NoData"; //showing empty value when printing the list.
         String[] tokens = s.split("-");

        switch (tokens.length) {
        case 5:
            comments.add(tokens[4]);                
        case 4:
            partner.add(tokens[3]);             
        case 3:
            useCaseIds.add(tokens[2]);
        case 2:
            lastNames.add(tokens[1]);
        case 1:
            firstNames.add(tokens[0]);
        default:
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("firstNames " + firstNames);
        System.out.println("lastNames " + lastNames);
        System.out.println("useCaseIds " + useCaseIds);
        System.out.println("partner " + partner);
        System.out.println("comments " + comments);
    }

}
```

Tested on [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/)

Comment: thanks.Is there any better way to implement this kind of logic instead of using switch statements.

Comment: Not really, you could use multiple `if`s. I think using the `switch` with omitting the `break;` is a nice trick, though hard to understand for some.

Comment: @user222 I think you should create a `User` object if you plan on importing multiple strings `s` instead of having 5 separate lists. The reason is that if one match is missing data e.g. the comments then the 5 lists get out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

You ask if there is a better solution than `switch` with tricky drop-throughs.  How about this?

The switch is replaced with a loop, and we get around the variable names problem by making an array of the lists.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> useCaseIds = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> partner = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String>[] lists = new List<String>[]{
            firstNames, lastNames, useCaseIds, partner, comments
        };

        // String s = "Annie-Marie--Joe";
        String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782-Joe-NoData";

        String[] tokens = s.split("-");

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(lists.length, tokens.length); i++) {
             lists[i].add(tokens[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("firstNames " + firstNames);
        System.out.println("lastNames " + lastNames);
        System.out.println("useCaseIds " + useCaseIds);
        System.out.println("partner " + partner);
        System.out.println("comments " + comments);
    }
}
```

Having said this, what you are doing here is not good OO design.  What you should do is create a `Person` class to represent the information in a line in your input file.  Then replace the 5 separate lists of strings with a single `List<Person>`.

Comment: True.  I have fixed that.